# Unix - Bash - How to split a file according to specific rules

Tags: bash, unix

I have thousands of files on unix, that I need to split into two parts, according to following rules:

1) Find the first occurence of the string ' JOB ' in the file

2) Find the first line after the occurence found in point 1) which doesn't end with comma ','

3) Split the file after the line found in point 2)

Below is a sample file, this one should be split after the line ending with the string 'DUMMY'.

```
//*%OPC SCAN                              
//*%OPC FETCH MEMBER=$BUDGET1,PHASE=SETUP 
// TESTJOB JOB USER=TESTUSER,MSGLEVEL=5,
//                           CLASS=H,PRIORITY=10,
//                           PARAM=DUMMY
//*
//STEP1 EXEC DB2OPROC
//...
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: By writing a script. What have you tried ?

Comment: thanks all, found the problem, the files were originated from mainframe, so the lines were extended with spaces to a certain line length, obviously "sed" to find the line not ending with "," didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this task:

```
$ cat data1 
//*%OPC SCAN                              
//*%OPC FETCH MEMBER=$BUDGET1,PHASE=SETUP 
// TESTJOB JOB USER=TESTUSER,MSGLEVEL=5,
//                           CLASS=H,PRIORITY=10,
//                           PARAM=DUMMY
//*
//STEP1 EXEC DB2OPROC
//...
$ sed -n '0,/JOB/ p;/JOB/,/[^,]$/ p' data1 | uniq > part1
$ sed '0,/JOB/ d;0,/[^,]$/ d' data1 > part2
$ cat part1 
//*%OPC SCAN                              
//*%OPC FETCH MEMBER=$BUDGET1,PHASE=SETUP 
// TESTJOB JOB USER=TESTUSER,MSGLEVEL=5,
//                           CLASS=H,PRIORITY=10,
//                           PARAM=DUMMY
force@force-virtual-machine:~$ cat part2
//*
//STEP1 EXEC DB2OPROC
//...
$
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is:

1. `find` all files to be checked;
2. `grep` each file for specified pattern with `-n` to get the match line if it matches;
3. split the matching file by `head` or `tail` with line number got in step two.

what's more, grep can handle reg expression. such as `grep -n "^.*JOB.*[^,]$" filename`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a couple of steps using `awk`/`sed`:

```
line=`awk '/JOB/,/[^,]$/ {x=NR} END {print x}' filename`
next=`expr $line + 1`
sed -ne "1,$line p" filename > part_1
sed -ne "$next,\$ p" filename > part_2
```

where `filename` is the name of your file. This will create two files: `part_1` and `part_2`.

Comment: Running Awk just to get the line number is stilly. This should be refactored to a single Awk script.

Comment: You are correct, of course you can refactor into a single script (e.g. below). However, the multi-step solution is easier to follow if you're not familiar with awk etc, which OP presumably isn't (hence he's asking the question). An example single-script solution is: `awk 'BEGIN {outf="part1"} /JOB/ {start=1} {print >outf} start && /[^,]$/ {outf="part2"}' filename`